# How to change color of the first and last row in the group UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, ios6

How to change color of the first and last row in the group UITableView?

I would like to sharing my solution with you but I don't know how, so I create this question. sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

In your `UITableViewDataSource` method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` do something like this, after your cell has been set up:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 || 
    indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // or anything you want.
}
```

Comment: look to my answer. you can change the color of first or last cell or middle cells each separately.

Comment: Yaser, if you post a question and want to answer it yourself, check the **Answer your own question** option, so the question doesn't show up until you've posted your answer too. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];


    for (int x = 0; x < [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]; x++) {

        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:x];

        int d = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

        if(indexPath.section == x){

            if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == d-1) {

                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            }else{

                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            }

        }
    }

    return cell;   
}
```